# In React, how do I set the href attribute of an <a> tag to the value of an environment variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have a URL in my react app:

```
<a href={process.env.ADMIN_URL} className="nav-link">Admin</a>
```

And in my `.env` file I have:

```
ADMIN_URL=http://localhost:3001
```

In the rendered result, there appears to be no `href` attribute:

[image]

If I do this instead:

```
const myUrl = "http://localhost:3001/"

[...]

<a href={myUrl} className="nav-link">Admin</a>
```

It works.

I used `create-react-app` to create this project, and I'm running it using the development server by running `npm run start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Create React App you can set environment variables in a `.env` file at the root of your project. All variables whose name start with REACT_APP_ will be made accessible under process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLE_NAME.

See the [Create React App doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) for more details

Comment: Ah, so I'm missing that prefix basically?

Comment: Yes, since your code will eventually run in a browser and you do not have access to the browser environment, these are not really environment variables. You do have environment variables available at build time (when you run `npm build` on your machine or server). Create React App uses Webpack under the hood to copy paste values in to your code based on the current environment during the app build and it needs to know what to look for, hence the prefix.